# Configuring a cache server on a Laravel application hosted on the cloud

Tags: php, caching, heroku, laravel

I am using Laravel framework and I host my staging and production environments on Heroku.

I would like to use a cache such as Memcached. On my local machine, everything runs fine and I can store values and retrieve them in the cache I run.

However once deployed on Heroku, setting and accessing keys in the cache does not do anything neither result in an error.

After some investigation, I believe the problem lies in the connection to the Memcached service I use (in my case Memcached cloud).

How can I set up Laravel for my staging and production environments to connect to an external Memcached provider?

I tried using the username and password provided after the installation of Memcached cloud on my application, but Laravel does not use them.

In cache.php

```
$memcachedURL = parse_url(getenv("MEMCACHEDCLOUD_SERVERS"));
```

...

```
'memcached' => array(

    array(
                'host' => $memcachedURL["host"], 
                'port' => $memcachedURL["port"], 
                'weight' => 100,
                'username' => getenv("MEMCACHEDCLOUD_USERNAME"),
                'password' => getenv("MEMCACHEDCLOUD_PASSWORD")
                ),
)
```

Should I write a Memcached connector to use such a username and password? If yes, would you have some references about how to start doing it?

Comment: Not a Laravel expert, but note that Memcached Cloud should be connected to using SASL (binary) Memcached protocol from Heroku.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @tscheepers and @atyagi, here is the code I use to make it work with Memcached cloud and Heroku.

I also made a package available on Packagist and Github, https://github.com/kintso/memcachedcloud-laravel

Create a Memcached cloud connector

```
class MemcachedCloudConnector {

/**
 * Extend the Memcached connection to use MemcachedCloud via Heroku
 *
 * @param array $servers
 * @throws \RuntimeException
 * @return \Memcached
 */
public function connect(array $servers)
{
    $memcached = $this->getMemcached();

    // Set Elasticache options here
    if (defined('\Memcached::OPT_BINARY_PROTOCOL')) {
        $memcached->setOption(Memcached::OPT_BINARY_PROTOCOL, true);
    }

    $memcached->addServers(array_map(function($server) { return explode(':', $server, 2); }, explode(',', $_ENV['MEMCACHEDCLOUD_SERVERS'])));
    $memcached->setSaslAuthData($_ENV['MEMCACHEDCLOUD_USERNAME'], $_ENV['MEMCACHEDCLOUD_PASSWORD']);

    if ($memcached->getVersion() === false) {
        throw new \RuntimeException("Could not establish Memcached connection.");
    }

    return $memcached;
}

/**
 * Get a new Memcached instance.
 *
 * @return \Memcached
 */
protected function getMemcached()
{
    return new Memcached;
}

}
```

Bind it to the IoC via a service provider

```
// Based on https://github.com/atyagi/elasticache-laravel

class MemcachedCloudServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

/**
 * Indicates if loading of the provider is deferred.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
protected $defer = false;

/**
 * Register the service provider.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function register()
{
        $servers = $this->app['config']->get('cache.memcached');
        $memcachedCloud = new MemcachedCloudConnector();
        $memcached = $memcachedCloud->connect($servers);

        $this->app->getProviderRepository()->load($this->app, array('Illuminate\Cache\CacheServiceProvider'));

        $this->app->make('cache')->extend('memcached', function() use ($memcached) {
            /** @noinspection PhpUndefinedNamespaceInspection */
            /** @noinspection PhpUndefinedClassInspection */
            return new \Illuminate\Cache\Repository(
                new \Illuminate\Cache\MemcachedStore($memcached, $this->app['config']->get('cache.prefix')));
        });
}

/**
 * Get the services provided by the provider.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function provides()
{
    return array();
}
}
```

Do not forget to refer to the new service provider in your app.php file and ensure your Memcached ids are registered as environment variables in your Heroku app.

Answer (score 1):

I was just investigating the same thing. There seem to be two ways to go about it.

1. You could create your own Cache extension. http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/extending#cache
2. You extend `\Illuminate\Cache\MemcachedConnector` to include the `setSaslAuthData` call and bind it into the IoC container.

The `MemcachedConnector` class (https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.2/src/Illuminate/Cache/MemcachedConnector.php) has a `getMemcached()` method which returns an instance of `Memcached`. According to `http://php.net/manual/en/memcached.setsaslauthdata.php` you can set SASL authentication credentials on the Memcached instance.

So you could subclass `\Illuminate\Cache\MemcachedConnector` and bind it to `$app['memcached.connector']` in your own service provider. You subclass could then override the `getMemcached()` to include the credentials. More on IoC base extensions: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/extending#ioc-based-extension.

Comment: I came across a similar extension built for Elasticache https://github.com/atyagi/elasticache-laravel. It uses the second solution you mentioned. I adapted it for Memcached Cloud and did not overwrite the getMemcached() method but the connect() method. I am pasting the code as an answer